# Symfony confirm message if a condition is true (submit_to_remote)

Tags: symfony1, conditional-statements, confirm, link-to-remote

I made a radiobutton based form in Symfony. I'd like to make a confirm message, IF a radio button checked. This is my code, but it's not exactly what I want:

```
            <?php echo jq_submit_to_remote('deleteButton','Törlés', array(
                'url' => 'editCategory/deleteSubmenu',
                'with'=>"'value=' + getSelectedRadio()",
                'condition' => 'getSelectedRadio() != undefined',
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
            )) ?>
```

This makes the confirm message in every case. How can I add condition to the confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with symfony's helpers, you'll need to write your own JS code. That's the recommended way to do it anyway - there's a reason the javascript helpers got deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So... I write a JS code which checks the radiobuttons, and after I have to connect to doctrine... how can I do this from JS?

Comment: You either make an ajax request, or redirect the whole page to the url you have in your question. For the first you should use some javascript framework, like jquery. For the latter, simple javascript is enough.